# Better approach to mimic a vertical scroller for a canvas?

Tags: html, css, layout, controls

I would like to have a vertical scroll bar that sits at the right of a canvas and whose height is equal to canvas'.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

A mini-viewport in the web page that is vertically scrollable, like this:

[image]

In the picture above, the vertical scrollbar in reality is not related to picture box on its left.

The content of the picture box is dynamically generated according the scroll bar position.

In other terms, say picture is 256x256, it'll always be of that size, its content is updated according scrolling position; hence why I need such mechanism.

**What I tried:**

Came up with a vertical input range that I had to rotate by 180 degrees so that its beginning is at the top instead of bottom.

Furthermore, trying various flex properties to suppress that space between it and the canvas didn't work.

The only thing that worked was to hardcode the width of the input range.

Overall, it's pretty brittle and probably not the right way to do it.

```html
<html>

<body>
    <style>
        #my-div {
            display: flex;
        }

        #my-canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 256px;
            height: 256px;
        }

        #my-slider {
            appearance: slider-vertical;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            width: 16px;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="my-div">
        <canvas id="my-canvas">

        </canvas>
        <input id="my-slider" type="range">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Question:**

Is there a better way to make a vertical scroll bar that fits next to a canvas?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding. What is it that you intend to be scrollable?

Comment: @AHaworth I've added explanations along a picture that explains it.

Comment: I would still rather use a "real" scrollbar, than try to emulate it with a range slider. Have one div element that is as high as the canvas, with `overflow:auto`, and, stick another div with whatever height you need to cover with your scroll in there. The `scrollTop` property of the outer div will tell you how far it has been scrolled down.

Comment: Yep, that is indeed much better!

Comment: @CBroe Talked too fast, no way to specify the granularity of the stock scroller.